# How to Disconnect dialled call after some time automatically in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I have required to disconnect outgoing call on specific number when apps launch.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

I use following code.

```
public void disconnect()
{
    EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent pressEndKey = new EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent( KeyCodeEvent.KEY_DOWN, (char) Keypad.KEY_END, 0);  

        EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent releaseEndKey = new EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent( KeyCodeEvent.KEY_UP, (char) Keypad.KEY_END, 0);  

        EventInjector.invokeEvent(pressEndKey);  
        EventInjector.invokeEvent(releaseEndKey);
}
```

Comment: Hello    I have required to end call without pressing any key.

Comment: You need not to press any key. The function will automatically invoke 'end key' listener.For more details you can refer docs of EventInjector class.

Comment: This is somehow hackish but it is the only way.